# Can WinSCP be used to access Google Cloud Storage bucket using the 'Amazon S3' file protocol?

Tags: winscp, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

Can `WinSCP` be used to access *Google Cloud Storage bucket* using the *Amazon S3* file protocol using the *HMAC keys*?
I tired but got the following error:

> Expected request type in credential scope to be "goog4_request" or "aws4_request". Received "aws4_reqb0628218c0b4a66bf165a0406f92cb571a3ff0628a157fd70ebd72b0fd051d23".

I was able to use the S3 browser using the type *'S3 Compatible Storage'* type and the HMAC keys.
But the free version of S3 browser allows saving only two accounts and I have many more accounts to access, hence relying on WinSCP instead.

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP can be used to access Google Cloud Storage bucket. You need at least WinSCP 5.19.

If you follow the instructions, you should not get the problem you are describing.

Basically, you just need to:

- In your Google Cloud Storage settings, select your project as the default interoperability project.
- In WinSCP, select the S3 protocol.
- Enter the Google request endpoint: `https://storage.googleapis.com`.
- Enter your interoperability access keys.

For details, refer to WinSCP article [Accessing Google Cloud Storage bucket with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_google_bucket).